# React Native App keeps closing after opening it without crashing

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I published my .apk file using the link https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android and I installed it on my android device. When I open it, it immediately crashes.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there might be many reasons for this happening. But still sharing what solved my crash.

I had enabled proguard in my release apk, I just disabled it.

In `[project-root]/android/app/build.gradle` file,

I changed from

```
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true
```

to

```
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to trace this will be using adb, either print adb log OR connect your device with release build via usb, open your project in Android studio, run app & check logs

For reference
https://medium.com/@impaachu/react-native-android-release-build-crash-on-device-14f2c9eacf18