# React-native app keeps stopping on emulator

Tags: react-native

> I am not getting any error in my app while running (npx react-native
>   run-android) and react-native start but it is showing on the emulator
>   that your app keeps stopping.

[image: npx react-native run-android output]

Comment: can you post the log of the emulator , this is the log of building app not the log when you install and start app on emulator

Comment: Start logcat to view messages directly at the emulator. There are standalone tools to use logcat, I prefer Android-Studio, which also make debugging easier.
If you found some logs, please post it here. (Maybe similar issue like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60428486/react-native-app-keeps-closing-after-opening-it-without-crashing)